# Regexp Pattern Matching Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have data of the format file.txt

```
afsdfds/sfsd/sfdsf/VISA_CTS_ec0cbf000an2n06x5_G3B7I1/sfdfdvged/sdvdsfgv ec0cbf000an2n06x5 
afsggggdfds/sfsd/sfdsf/VISA_CTS_ec0clb000an2n10x5_G3B7I1/sfdggggfdvged/sdvdsfgv ec0clb000an2n10x5 
afsdfds/fdddo9045374857_234242/sfsd/sfdsf/VISA_CTS_ec0cilb000an2n16x5_G3B7I1/sfdfdvged/sdvdsfgv ec0cilb000an2n16x5 
qweryt/visa_ec0ceb000an2n20x5_tyiuop/gfds_sfgds_/clock_VISA_CTS_ec0ceb000an2n20x5_G3B7I1/hjkhfjhfd/asdfasdf ec0ceb000an2n20x5
```

I am using in Tcl

```
package require fileutil 

set filename file.txt 
set pattern {ec0cbf|ec0clb|cb|ceb} 
puts "[llength [fileutil::grep $pattern $filename]] occurances" 

$tcl> 7 occurances
```

I want only the right most values from file.txt to be returned by my regexp and my final answer to be 3 occurances (ec0cbf000an2n06x5 ec0ceb000an2n20x5 ec0ceb000an2n20x5) ) instead of 7 as I am not detecting "cilb"

This file.txt is dynamic data`

Comment: I think both of these do what you're looking for, but I'm not positive: ` (.*(?:ec0cbf|ec0clb|cb|ceb).*$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW7bY5/2)) or ` (\S*(?:ec0cbf|ec0clb|cb|ceb).*$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW7bY5/1))

Comment: The answer I'm showing gives 3 matches, which is what your question says you want. In the demos that I linked, "cilb" isn't matched.  Are the demos not showing that for you?

Comment: @Jota Yes, this is exactly the regex that I was looking for. Thanks ! It is working.

Comment: " (\S*(?:ec0cbf|ec0clb|ec0ceb).*?$)"

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sW7bY5/3

Comment: `fileutil::grep` returns effectively a list of `$filename:$lineNumber:$lineContents`; i.e., it always returns whole lines. What were you trying to do with the results again? I'm confused by your question…

Answer (score 0):

This can solve your problem:

```
set a [open test.txt r]
set data [read $a]
set c [split $data "\n"]
set cnt 0

% foreach d $c {
    if {[regexp {ec0cbf|ec0clb|cb|ceb} $d]} {
        puts "[lindex $d  end]"
        incr cnt
    }
}
puts $cnt
```

Comment: [edit] your post to add more information, there's a link just under it. comments are bad for code/output formatting

Comment: Output will be like this 

% foreach d $c { 

if {[regexp {ec0cbf|ec0clb|cb|ceb} $d]} {

 puts "[lindex $d end]" 

incr cnt
 }
 } 

ec0cbf000an2n06x5 

ec0clb000an2n10x5 

ec0ceb000an2n20x5 

% puts $cnt 

3